# How to log which is the Pretty print like pprint by clojure.tools.logging?

Tags: logging, clojure, pprint

I am using `org.clojure/tools.logging`.
I want to get a function which can pretty print the log, but I can't find it.
For example, the content which i want to print is

```
{:status 401,
 :headers {"Content-Type" "application/octet-stream"},
 :body {:error "You don't login."}}
```

but i call the function name is `info`,I get this

```
{:status 401, :headers {Content-Type application/octet-stream}, :body {:error You don't login.}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.pprint :as pprint])

(defn pformat [& args]
        (with-out-str
          (apply pprint/pprint args)))
```

Then:

```
(require '[clojure.tools.logging :as log])

(log/info (pformat {:status 401,
                    :headers {"Content-Type" "application/octet-stream"},
                    :body {:error "You don't login."}}))
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
Apr 29, 2015 9:43:40 AM user invoke
INFO: {:headers {"Content-Type" "application/octet-stream"},
 :status 401,
 :body {:error "You don't login."}}
```